# Menu slide with link to section of page smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, slider

Im trying to have my div menu hide when i click on a label and at the same time scroll down smoothly to a section of the page. The site can slide down to where i want but i cant hide the menu. Im using CSS3 and Jquery, im still very new to Jquery, but maybe i can do this with only Jquery? If i can do this by only using a link or something other than a label thats not a problem. Im open to suggestions.
Thanks for your help.

CSS:

```
<style>
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container{
    width: 80%;
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: #A77676;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #7B87FF;
}
.menu{
    width: 200px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: #C6C6C6;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;

}
.menu-slide{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8BE2FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 11;
}
.jqueryscrollto{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1500px;
}

/************************************/
label.button{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF0000;
    /*background-color: #1800FF;*/
    display: inline-block;
}
label.linkbutton{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #36FF00;
    display: inline-block;
}
/********slide starter****/
input.toggle ~ .menu-slide{
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
input.toggle:checked ~ .menu-slide{
    transform: translateX(-200px);
}
input.toggle{
    display: none;
}
/*****************************/
input.togglelink ~ .menu-slide{
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
input.togglelink:checked ~ .menu-slide{
    transform: translateX(-200px);
}
input.togglelink{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="menu-cont">

    <div class="menu">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="iconbtn">
        <label class="button" for="iconbtn">ICON BUTTON</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="togglelink" id="linkbtn" data-href="#SCROLL">
      <div class="menu-slide">
        <div class="menu-content">
          <h2>SLIDER</h2>
          <label class="linkbutton" for="linkbtn">ABOUT US-LINKBTN</label>
        </div>
      </div><!--menu slide -->
    </div><!-- menu -->

  </div><!-- menu-cont -->
  <div class="jqueryscrollto">I WANT TO SCROLL HERE</div><label id="SCROLL"></label>

</div><!-- #container -->
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
try {$('input').click(function(){
 href=$(this).data('href');
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
} catch (error) { throw error; }
</script>
</body
```

I put the jquery inside the bottom part of the HTML body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just stuck to the books and learned the basics :)

```
$(function() {
$(document.onload)

  var left = true;
  $(".button, .icon").click(function() {
     $(".slide-container").animate({
        left: left ? "0px" : "-200px"
     }, 1000);

     left = !left;

  });

  $('.button').on('click', function(){

    href=$(this).data('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 1000);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to hide html element using Js

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(1000);
    });
```

Comment: So do you think it is best to forget the CSS3 completely and go with Jquery only? Thanks for a quick response.

Comment: Well to me Jquery method seems to be safer, since different browsers render css a bit differently.

Comment: Right.. makes sence. The only problem is im still very new to jquery. But i'll try my best with what you are suggesting. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: not exactly the effect i was looking for.. i want to make the div "slide" when i press a link and at the same time scroll down to a specific section of a page.

Comment: Not quiet what i was looking for. But its a start. Im trying to find out how to connect the jquery scrollTop with a jquery div slide.